# PHPWord page numbers ignoring first page

Tags: php, page-numbering, phpword

I'm using PHPWord to generate a document. I'm a but stuck on what to do with my page numbers.
Using `addPreserveText('Page {PAGE}');` I can show my page number.

But I have a front page and I want page 2 to have page number 1, page 3 to have page number 2, etcetera.

Does anybody know what I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which Version of PHPWord you are using and mine is heavily patched, so line numbers are surely not correct. This is very hardcoded. If you need a patch where you can set the start number from `$phpWord->createSection()` you have to wait a little bit. I'm implementing it right now:-)

In `Writer/Word2007/Document.php -> private function _writeEndSection` add the following lines:

```
$objWriter->startElement('w:pgNumType');
$objWriter->writeAttribute('w:start', '0');
$objWriter->endElement();
```

It should be in the w:sectPr Element.
I added the snippet just before this line:

```
$objWriter->startElement('w:pgMar');
```

Change the w:start number to any value.
Hope this helps.